# Pandas .replace() int by boolean

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to replace all `0`s and `1`s by `True` and `False`. I tried the below code but the data frame doesn't change.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     'B': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

print(df.replace(1, True).replace(0, False)) 
print(df.dtypes)
```

Console output:

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  0  0
3  1  0
4  0  0
5  1  1
6  0  1

A    int64
B    int64
dtype: object

   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  0  0
3  1  0
4  0  0
5  1  1
6  0  1

A    int64
B    int64  
dtype: object
```

Comment: df.astype(bool)?

Comment: @Vaishali that works! Any idea why the above code doesn't work?

Comment: With `replace`, try passing a dictionary. `replace` is iffy and some things require dictionaries. This is by design: `df.replace({1: True, 0: False})`

Comment: @coldspeed That works!